# Different formula for Claude Shannon's Entropy or "Uncertainty"

Tags: entropy, information-theory

In his classic paper about Information theory, Claude Shannon provides a formula for entropy which is now widely used.

But is there a different formula for entropy that satisfies all the constraints of entropy:

- H should be continuous in p
- H should be monotonically increasing in n, when pi are all equal pi = 1/n
- If a choice be broken down into two successive choices, the original H should be the weighted sum
  of the individual values of H

Comment: Show the formula you're talking about. You're discussing its components but didn't put the full expression

Answer (score 0):

I think any [reverse parabolic curve](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=x(1-x)) satisifes all the constraints of a Entropy function required by Claude Shannon.

But the formula Shannon came up with is very superior to all of these functions because it also captures data required to encode all the events, which most of these parabolic curves don't do.